# Should web service running within Amazon cluster consumed by other services running within EC2 use HTTPS?

Tags: security, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm developing a web service: a Heroku add-on to be used by other Heroku applications. The server providing the service and all Heroku applications run within Amazon EC2. Should my service be available over HTTPS or is it an unnecessary overkill? What are common practices?

I worry about HTTPS performance overheat and more complicated client code (client would need to manage a key to verify the service identity). It also seems that man in the middle attack would require compromise of Amazon infrastructure, which would enable plenty other ways to compromise the service, even if the traffic was encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

- Using HTTPS [adds less than 1%](http://ssl.entrust.net/blog/?p=455) of additional CPU overhead on modern hardware.
- A man-in-the-middle attack would not require compromise of Amazon infrastructure.  It can occur anywhere between the client and the server.  And just because AWS's infrastructure itself is secure, doesn't mean that the resources that you've provisioned in their cloud are.

> Should my service be available over HTTPS or is it an unnecessary overkill? What are common practices?

Without more specifics, it's hard to recommend anything.  Does your API return random cat pictures or does it store medical records?  SSL is becoming more-and-more common though.  If you're even contemplating it, then there's a good chance that it's a reasonable idea.

Comment: But if clients and the server run within the same cluster (as will be the case with my add-on), there doesn't seem to be anything between them other than Amazon infrastructure.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "cluster." Is this a Heroku term?  But with AWS, unless you're using a VPC, everyone has access to everyone else's instances.  The only thing providing a bit of defense is the EC2 security group and whatever application or system-level security is present on the instance itself.

Comment: Interesting, so an instance can intercept network traffic that is not directed to this instance?

Comment: Well, not easily, anyhow.  AWS doesn't allow promiscuous network operations. But security in depth is proper security, meaning you should always have multiple layers of defense.  I don't know enough about Heroku to be able to comment on their network security.  But practically speaking, protecting your data at rest (in the database) is far more important than protecting it in transit.